# XNA sprite loses pixels on a very pixelated image

Tags: c#, xna, sprite

So this may be a bit vague, but I'm having some issues. Basically, I am drawing my little ninja sprite (16x16px) and on 2 frames of his animation, he loses pixels on his headband. I have looked everywhere in an attempt to find an answer, but to no avail.

Original Sprite Sheet (Bugged frames are 4th row, 3rd and 4th frames):

[image]

[image]

After a little more investigation, it seems that the bugged pixels are due to the width of the sprite sheet. It almost seems random what pixels get messed up depending on the width. However, with a constant width, the messed up pixels are constant regardless of creating a new build or using an old one.

As you can see, the back of his headband is missing pixels. While it may not be game changing, it is very annoying and if anyone knows of a fix, that'd be great! Thanks guys!

Comment: Can you post the original sprite sheet, not just the screenshot of the issue happening?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that those pixels are magenta (255,0,255) which is automatically keyed out of the image as transparent by the SpriteTextureProcessor. If that is the case, change the pixels to be a slightly different color (255,1,255) or use the TextureProcessor for the content. You can do this in the properties window of the image file in your content project.

Comment: The sprite source is a 16x16px rectangle. The sprite sheet is fine, but somewhere along the line, the texture loses pixels in those few places.

Comment: Well, looks like based on your sprite sheet I guessed wrongly. I would still try a different content processor for the image and see if it persists.

Comment: On further investigation, it happens on more than just those frames. It happens on all frames that have pixels in the same column as that one. So on the 2nd to last row, when the sword comes down, the trail is all jagged. It's as if the game renders the image wrong, only on the row, the entire time.

Comment: So I did a little more messing around. The screw up pixels are somehow linked to the width of the image. Taking off the last 2 columns of pixels on my spritesheet yields  a few broken pixels here and there, not many. But Adding more to the width means even more screwy pixels. Not sure if using a different conent processor would make a difference. I'm a sort of C#/XNA noob, so I'm not quite sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

So a workaround I found is actually changing the size of the rectangle used to display the image. It was set to 100, setting it to 99 works and there is barely any visual difference.